# Filling struct arrays in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I have recently moved from C# to C and the memory stuff is absolutely wrecking me. I am writing a program, where I need to declare struct array and fill it one by one, but so far, I have not even been able to print it.
The arguments are supposed to be a string array. I am making a CMD thing, where id is the name of command, that is converted from string through enum. The arguments are the options for the command. So far, I have extracted id of command and char* to the individual options, but I need a way to store them. That is why Iam going for char**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    int id;
    char** arguments;
} myStruct_t;

void printStructs(myStruct_t* myStructs[])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%i %s", myStructs[i].id, myStructs[i].arguments[0]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char* strings[] = { "fooo", "ooof", "wack", "yeet", "bruh" };
    myStruct_t structs[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            structs[i].id = i;
            structs[i].arguments = strings[i];
        }
    }

    printStructs(&strings);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have: `void printStructs(myStruct_t* myStructs[])` ‚ you should be using `void printStructs(size_t n, myStruct_t myStructs[n])` where the calling code says how many structures are in the array (that's the `size_t n`), and you have an array of structures, not an array of pointers to structures.  Use one of `*` or `[]`, not both.  Sometimes you'll need both, but not now. Get into the habit of telling your functions how big the array is — it makes your code more reusable. (You could omit the `n` in `[n]` with no significant loss, but the C99 feature makes explicit what is otherwise implicit.)

Comment: You should enable warnings with your compiler. For GCC add `-Wall -Wextra`. This `structs[i].arguments = strings[i];` takes a `char*` and tries assigns it to a `char **` which should trigger some warning.